# python UnicodeDecodeEorror, even I use decode('utf-8')

Tags: python, decode

I use python to read some html, the page contains some japanese and chinese characters,

the code as:

```
response = urllib.urlopen(pageurl).read()
```

when I print the response, python tells me a DecodeError

then I changed the code as

```
response = urllib.urlopen(pageurl).read().decode("utf-8")
```

python still tells that

```
UnicodeDecodeError: "utf8" code can't decode byte 0xd1 in position...
```

what should I do....

by the way, the html chartset is gb2312...

Comment: Are you sure you get a **decode** error when printing? Can you please give us the *full* error message for that?

Comment: Also, you are decoding your page as UTF-8, while you *know* the characterset of the page is not UTF-8 but GB2312? Why?

Comment: whatever gbk or gb2312 or utf-8 are all gives me the UnicodeEncodeError, I don't know why....

Comment: Now you are talking about an **encode** error. That's something different. Please include the full traceback in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is using GB2312, it does not compatible with UTF-8, but can be considered a subset GBK, which is supported by Python decoder. Therefore, you should try `response = urllib.urlopen(pageurl).read().decode("gbk")` instead.